# How to open a new worksheet with formating already done?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I add new worksheets to my table with some values and formatting already present? What I have been doing is duplicating an existing worksheet and then manually deleting the values. It's a monthly workbook, so first worksheet is January then February, etc.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you want, if layout and formatting of each worksheet needs to be identical, you can group all 12 sheets, apply the layout and formatting to the first sheet, and it will be automatically transferred to the remaining 11 sheets (which you will have already inserted). You group sheets by holding down the shift-key and left-clicking on each sheet tab. To ungroup the sheets, left-click on the tab on one of sheets (without holding down the shift key).

Comment: But I'm still in the beginning of the tablebook, I'm in April, so I don't have the others sheets. What I want is that when I add another worksheet it automatically comes with the formatting I've made in the previous sheet.

Comment: Ah. See the instructions for creating a worksheet template at [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/insert-a-new-worksheet-HP005200889.aspx).